# C’est du / un grand n’importe quoi

Tags: articles

Bonjour,

> Je frissonne involontairement. Voilà, nous y sommes. La sorcellerie,
> nous y sommes arrivés. Mais non c’est **du** grand n’importe quoi.
>
> Je frissonne involontairement. Voilà, nous y sommes. La sorcellerie,
> nous y sommes arrivés. Mais non c’est **un** grand n’importe quoi.

Sur Internet, il y a plus de résultats contenant "du". D'après vous, quelle variante est la meilleure ?

Answer (score 1):

Dans ton texte, seul ***du*** est logique. Tu parles de la sorcellerie en général. ***Un*** grand n'importe quoi aurait pu être utilisé si tu avais parlé de quelque chose de précis, par exemple :

> *Ce que tu nous a montré, c'est **un**<sup>1</sup> grand n'importe quoi.* (*du* est aussi possible ici).

Attention, il faut une ponctuation après *non* (par exemple virgule ou point d'exclamation, tu peux aussi en mettre un à la fin) :

> *Mais non **!** C’est **du** grand n’importe quoi.*

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Apparemment inusité au Québec</sub>

Comment: Détail de ma région, j'ai été surpris par l'emploi avec _un_ que j'avais jamais vu ! Contrairement à des sites avec des domaines .fr, je ne le trouve pas une seule fois sur lapresse (820 fois avec du) puis seulement deux fois dans ledevoir, mais dans un cas où c'était précédé de la préposition _dans_, et je trouve ça plus euphonique avec _un_ dans ce contexte mais je pense qu'au Qc avec _un_ est inusité, dans presque tous les cas je dirais _du_.

Comment: Merci. _Attention, il faut une ponctuation après "non"_  --- En effet, il est préférable d'y mettre une virgule ou un point d'exclamation, mais je ne pense pas que ce soit une faute de laisser la phrase telle quelle, sans signe de ponctuation.

Comment: @EylaChu-Generis Donc, on n'y dit pas non plus *un portnawak* ;-)

Comment: @Oreste *Mais non c'est du grand n'importe quoi* m'aurait valu 1/2 point en moins dans les dictées de mon enfance. *Mais non* et *c'est du grand n'importe quoi* sont des propositions indépendantes qui ne sont pas liées par un conjonction., la virgule s'impose.

Comment: Voilà, maintenant je comprends d'où vient ton amour pour les précisions (manuscule dans les titres). :) Heureusement que je ne suis pas allée à ton école ! // _sont des propositions indépendantes_ --- _Mais non_ est si court qu'il serait possible d'omettre la virgule pour alléger la phrase.

Comment: En fait, c'est intéressant, nos habitudes. Je me souviens maintenant. Au début, je posais des questions à une personne qui omettais des virgules si elle pouvait le faire. C'était bizarre pour moi parce qu'en russe on en met vraiment partout, par exemple devant "parce que", puis je me suis habituée à cette absence. :)

Comment: @Oreste J'aime bien *manuscule* ;-) Une majuscule qui se refuse à l'être.

Answer (score 0):

En effet « du » est énormément utilisé en comparaison à « un ».

[image]

Le Wiktionnaire mentionne « grand n'importe quoi » en tant que locution nominale, et donc, a priori on doit pouvoir utiliser plusieurs articles.

> ([Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/grand_n%E2%80%99importe_quoi))  **Étymologie**    Composé de *grand* et de *n’importe quoi*.
> Locution nominale
> grand n’importe quoi \ɡʁɑ̃ n‿ɛ̃.pɔʁ.tə kwa\
> Chose complètement absurde, très extravagante.

Étant donné que cette expression ne s'applique qu'à des choses telles que des conceptions de l'esprit, il n'y a jamais d'inexactitude en utilisant cette locution selon son aspect massif ; par contre, il existe la possibilité de ne pas utiliser  « un » correctement. Si l'on parle des actions  de quelqu'un selon le point de vue que les  actes qui  caractérisent ce comportement  sont irrationnels, il devient plus ou moins nécessaire qu'il existe un cadre dans lequel  ce comportement est observé, et alors ce cadre peut être considéré sur le plan de l'énumérable et déterminé par « un » .

- Sa marche à suivre  pour dissuader  le personnel de voler la firme est un grand n'importe quoi.

Cependant, s'il s'agit de comportement en général, « un » ne convient pas si bien ; il semble que le concept soit plus proprement traité en tant que concept massif.

- Ses faits et actes pendant une courte période pendant qu'il était à ce poste sont **du** grand n'importe quoi.

En conclusion, « du » est plus sûr.